# Using baseurl in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, base-url

I have some issues loading a site that apparently has to do with needing to properly set a baseurl.  The main site is http://www.oklahomachristianacademy.org and the site address I need to have open is a string that returns as

`applewebdata://F6224B10-25ED...`

So, in my code I thought this would work to set the baseurl and the string attached above to load into the app.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSURL *theurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.oklahomachristianacademy.org/"];
[savedweb loadHTMLString:(NSString *)link baseURL:(NSURL *)theurl];
}
```

However, this does not work, and the UIWebview simply displays the applewebdata:// line again.  What am I missing?

Comment: @iPatel is that a question, or what?

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```
//NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://cagt.bu.edu/page/IPhone-summer2010-wiki_problemsandsolutions";
//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: This does not help any.  Did you read the question?  The url I am trying to open will not because it is a relative URL and it comes in as applewebdata://  I am trying to take the relative URL and attach it to the baseURL.  Your code simply shows how to open any webpage, nothing more.